# ¿Cómo puedo borrar el fondo blanco de una imagen como mask de pillow?

Tags: python

he estado intentando borrar el fondo blanco que contiene una imagen para poder pegarla a otra pero no lo he logrado alguno sabe como, que me pueda ayudar. Aquí dejo el código que tengo hecho y aquí dejo la imagen con el fondo blanco

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

````
        shirt = Image.open("shirt.jpg")
        new_shirt = ImageOps.fit(shirt,(900,300), method=0, bleed=0.0, centering=(1.0,1.0))
        masks = new_shirt.convert("RGBA")
        muppet.paste(new_shirt, (170,1070), masks)  
        muppet.save("after.jpg")```
````

Comment: Podrías mostrarnos uno de tus intentos para probarnos que hiciste ese esfuerzo para resolver tu problema por favor?

Comment: Si claro mira, espera la coloco

Comment: En realidad me refería a código, pues el que estaba en la pregunta me pareció que no intentas hacer transparente el fondo. Pero creo que entendí mal. De causalidad intentaste usar ImageOps.fit para quitar el fondo?

Comment: Ah disculpa entendí mal, use ImageOps.fit para recortar la imagen

Comment: No hay problema c: Entonces, te recomiendo que agregues a tu pregunta una demostracion de que sos parte del esfuerzo por responderla. Si no, pareciera que nos pides que lo hagamos por ti sin mas.